# Signing product stage while building app in xCode 6 takes too long

Tags: ios, xcode6, building

Everything was working perfectly, I didn't even notice that there is **signing product** stage while building app because it was so quick.

I didn't change anything and suddenly my app building time increased. It is stuck at **signing product** stage for about 5 minutes and after that period app builds normally.

Project is created with xCode 5.1.1 and now I'm using xCode 6.0.1. It was running well for some time after switching to new version of xCode.

Does anyone know why **signing product** stage time increased?

Answer (score 6):

I deleted xCode derived data folder and now everything is running smoothly

Comment: Derived data folder is local folder. In xCode go to Window->Organiser. When organizer open click on "Projects" and you will see there "Derived Data" and "Delete" button

Comment: To top on that, deleting derived folder won't make performance any good on my side (I use xcode 7.0 beta 6 7A192o). I use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1681369/571227) approach to skip png optimization done by xcode, then signing process is a lot faster according to these [steps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12764125/571227) done in xcode. I guess it might be skipping png optimization won't touch any resource, then thus no need to rebuild anything and resign the whole content.

Answer (score 6):

Also had this. I looked inside my Keychain and saw hundreds of duplicated certificates.

After deleting those, everything is now running smoothly.

Comment: this happened to me when switching to sierra and xcode 8. Countless hours wasted waiting for builds to complete. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This problem was driving me crazy after updating to Xcode 6.1, but couldn't find the solution. I recently updated my mac's memory because it was overall running slower after the update. After installing the new memory modules, surprisingly this problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this problem in every new version of Xcode and what i find is to try different internet connections and if still it not work then i use to turn on hotspot shield and it work most of the times.